# Achieving the optimal strike in squash: Is the wrist involved at all?

Tags: technique, squash

I am a sports enthusiast who has tried out many ball sports through-out my life with years of training in football (read: "soccer" if you are American) and basketball, as well as many hours of experience/play time in tennis and table tennis, although no formal training.

Several years back I decided to give a shot to squash with a friend, both never even watched a game at that point. By reading and watching and asking, I got to a level where I think I know the basics of the game. Since I am familiar with ball sports, I don't find it hard to follow the ball or use the walls/bounces to my best advantage. However I don't think I have the best technique.

So, the question; when I watch videos of pros or the people who compete in my town, I realize that they use the wrist to create a whip effect, or at least that's my interpretation of it. I believe I tend to be more stale in an effort to keep the racket in balance when striking the ball. I am not sure if I'd be able to deliver much power if ended up hitting the ball with a wrist-powered shot, compared to a whole-arm strike which puts much of the strain on the shoulders and the chest. Am I doing something wrong? Is it common practice to use the wrist in squash? Could it be so that my racket is simply too heavy for me (alt. I am not strong enough in my wrist to deliver proper shots with my racket?)

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm a lifelong squash player and what I'd say is don't worry so much about the wrist. You're going to use the wrist naturally as you make a full swing. You can add a bit of wrist at the point of impact to impart a little extra power, especially if you've taken a short backswing or you want to surprise your opponent by flicking the ball cross-court at the last second. But by and large, the wrist is a small percentage of your power. The real power comes from your LEGS. Step into each shot, move your arms through as you hit, and sure, use a bit of wrist, and you'll have yourself a powerful squash stroke. Keep up the playing, glad to see squash players out there!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, according to an excerpt from this UK [squash tips page](http://www.squashsite.co.uk/squash_tips.htm):

> **So compact your stroke by remembering to keep your elbow in and to use your wrist as much as possible.** Raise your shoulders, making
> your head position lower between them. Keep your knees bent and stay
> in the crouch position. A good practice technique is to crouch and
> have your elbow and knee meet at the point of contact with the ball.
> Not all players can do this. But, with time and with good footwork, it
> can be done. Practicing volleys can also help shorten your swing.
> **But, the wrist is the best mechanism in getting your swing and power to potential.**

Other pages also mention footwork and positioning as being important.